Create alias of verbatim environment with some optional arguments
I'd like to create an alias of the verbatim (xsim-based) environment
\begin{CacheMeCode}{tikzpicture, optional arguments}
\end{CacheMeCode}

to
\begin{tikzpicture}<optional arguments>
\end{tikzpicture}

Using
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{tikzpicture}{}{\CacheMeCode{tikzpicture}}{\endCacheMeCode}

works if I don't care about arguments, but I'd like also to support optional arguments, and
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{tikzpicture}{D<>{}}{\CacheMeCode{tikzpicture,#1}}{\endCacheMeCode}

fails with an error:
ERROR: File ended while scanning use of ^^M.

Any idea how to get this fixed?
MWE
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{robust-externalize}
\robExtConfigure{enable fallback to manual mode}
\cacheTikz
\robExtConfigure{
  add to preset={tikz}{
    add to preamble={
      \usepackage{pgfplots}
      \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
    }
  },
}

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{tikzpicture}{}{\CacheMeCode{tikzpicture}}{\endCacheMeCode}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [semithick, black]
table {%
0 0
0.0752933174371719 0.0355731099843979
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Could you explain the purpose of this? Why do you want to pass tikzpicture arguments using <> rather than []?

@cfr cause this option is not passed to tikzpicture, but to robust-externalize. This can be used for instance to forward some macro definition to robust externalize etc, and is linked with this issue https://github.com/leo-colisson/robust-externalize/issues/43 And I don't want to use [] precisely because I don't want it to interfere with tikzpicture's argument.

You probably don't want to do this generally (i.e. in the package) for the same reason memoize doesn't?

You mean verbatim inputs by default? Verbatim inputs can't really be used inside macros, and parsing verbatim inputs is also not so efficient (at least the way I proceed).

I meant you probably don't want to cache tikzpicture environments verbatim by default?

@cfr not really, unless I can find a really robust and efficient way to do that… (right now I use xsim for verbatim content that writes it in a file, which is quite ugly and not super efficient… and using the +v option would make it fail when used inside macros) Why are you asking?

But my question is actually fairly general and might apply to other environments.

Just interest, really, because I'd been thinking about the memoize case.
